# Evaluate the integral $\iint_S(x)dy\wedge dz+(x+y)dz\wedge dx+(x^2+2z)dx\wedge dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, differential-forms, surface-integrals

In a problem from my multivariable integration class, i've reached this problem. I will thank any comment with advice or answer. The problem asks me to calculate the integral
$$\iint_S(x)dy\wedge dz+(x+y)dz\wedge dx+(x^2+2z)dx\wedge dy$$
Being $S$ the surface of the solid $V$ limited by:
$$S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}:2x^2+y^2=4z\},$$
$$S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}:x^2+2z=2\}.$$
I'm told to solve twice it using two different methods: **direct integration** and **Gauss' Theorem (divergence)**. I've started trying with Gauss' Theorem, but i don't really get if i'm getting it correctly. The theorem tells that (under certaing region and surface conditions that this problem verifies) given $V$ a solid limited by a closed surface $S$, $N$ the normal vector, and $F=(P,Q,R)$ a vectorial field of class $C^1$,
$$\iint_{\partial V}F=\iint_S(F\cdot N)d\sigma = \iiint_V\text{div}(F)dxdydz.$$
Being $\text{div}(F)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial z}$.

I've started trying to find $P,Q,R$ in my example, but I'm not sure if that's possible, at least with my actual knowledge. What can I do to find my $\text{div}(F)$?.

For the direct integration part, I have no idea about how to do it. I specially struggle finding the integration limits.

Bounty edit: I need a step-by-step solution for both methods: direct integration and Gauss' Theroem (Divergence Theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i)
 $ D = \{ (x,y,0)| 4x^2+y^2\leq 4\} $ Here $S_i$ is a graph surface over $D$. And assume that they enclosed a solid body $T$

ii) Consider a vector field $ X$ so that we have 1-form $ w(V) = \langle X,V \rangle $. Hence we have a formula 
$$ d(\ast w) = {\rm div}\ X\cdot \nu $$ where $
 \ast$ is a **Hodge star** and $\nu$ is a volume form (cf 12 page in the book Differential forms
 and application - do Carmo).

When we define $\ast w:= x dy \wedge dz +(x+y) dz\wedge dx + (x^2+2z)
 dx\wedge dy $, then by definition of Hodge star, $$ w= xdx + (x+y)dy + (x^2 +2z)dz $$

That is, we can find $X =(x,x+y,x^2+2z)$ so that ${\rm div}\ X =4$

iii) (cf 63 page)

\begin{align*}\int_{\partial T}\ \ast w&=_{{\rm Stokes\ Theorem}}\ \int_T \ d(\ast w) \\&=\int_T\ {\rm div}\ X\cdot \nu\\&=4\int_{D}\ \bigg(1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}\bigg)
\cdot d{\rm Area}_D\\ &=4\int_{-2}^2\ \frac{4}{3} 
 \sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{4}}^3 \ dy \\&=4\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}
 \ \frac{8}{3}\cos^4 t\ dt  = 4\pi
\end{align*}
**[Another solution]**  By considering $S_1\bigcap S_2 $, we define $
  D\ :\ x^2+ \frac{y^2}{4} \leq 1$

Hence the solid $V$ has bottom face $B$ : $(x,y,
\frac{2x^2+y^2}{4}),\ (x,y)\in D$ and top face $T$ :
$(x,y,1-\frac{x^2}{2}),\ (x,y)\in D$.

Hence when $w= xdydz + (x+y)dz dx+(x^2+2z)dxdy $, then $$ \int_S \
w=\int_T\ w- \int_B\ w$$

Here \begin{align*} \int_T \ w &= \int_D\ x dy d(1-\frac{x^2}{2} )
\\&+ (x+y) d(1-\frac{x^2}{2}) dx +(x^2+2( 1-\frac{x^2}{2} ) )dxdy
\\&=\int_D\ (x^2+2)dxdy  \\
\int_B\ w &=\int\ xdyd ( \frac{2x^2+y^2}{4} )
+(x+y)d(\frac{2x^2+y^2}{4}) dx + (x^2+2\frac{2x^2+y^2}{4} )
dxdy\\&=\int_D\ x^2dxdy
\\ \int_S\ w&=\int_D\ 2dxdy =4\pi \end{align*}

Comment: And the direct integration method? Also, could you elaborate a bit more in your step-by-sep explanation? I don't fully get it. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But is this Direct integration or Gauss Theorem?

Comment: What is $\nu$ exactly? I mean it's vector components, and how do you get it.

Comment: I'm sorry but don't understand your solution

Comment: $\nu =dxdydz$ is a volume form on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Oh I see. And how do you make this step? $$\int_T\ {\rm div}\ X\cdot \nu=\int_{D}\ \bigg(1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}\bigg)
\cdot d{\rm Area}_D$$ (In your first solution)

Comment: Also thanks for the edit! I guess I'll be able to understand it a lot better now, thank you.

Comment: Didn't you also forget the "$∧$" symbols between the $dx,dy,d(1−\frac{x^2}{2})$? Or can they just be removed without changing the solution?